# angular trigger a function conditionally when returning from navigating back

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular 13 Ionic 6 app, I have a "Helpers" component listing all helpers. This component also has a "refreshHelpers()" function that refreshes from the DB.

This component has a button to navigate to another component for ADDING a new helper record:

```
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/add-helper']" id="add-helper-button" shape="round" fill="clear">
```

The user may navigate "Back" without adding a new helper, or add a new helper.
After successfully adding (and saving in the DB) the new user, I want to go BACK to the helpers list, and call refreshHelpers() to reflect the changes in the DB.

If I understand correctly, I cannot emit any @Output flags as there is no parent-child relationship here (both components are directly registered under root).

The backend DB is manipulated by sending REST API requests to run stored functions on the DB server (this is not a RDBMS, but rather a Graph DB), so I cannot listen to it as an observable).

I prefer the app automatically navigates back to Helpers upon a successful addition of a new helper (and refresh), but manual "Back" navigation may also suffice, if it helps capture the back event + condition that a new record was saved.

How would you suggest I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I could think of 3 different ways to approach this:

1. Since the `list` and the `add` component are both directly under `root`, you can still use `@Output` to communicate between them by send a message to `root` which `root` will then perform the `refreshHelpers()` on the `list`. This is the easiest way to go but it is not scalable since if you ever want to re-arrange your components it will break. This is also pretty messy and will add complexity to your `root` component.
2. Using a service to manage `helpers`. I'm not sure if you're doing all these http calls directly by injecting the `HttpClient` directly inside the component or if you're using a service for this? But in either way, having a service to manage `helpers` would do the trick. This service can keep an in memory list of all the `helpers` which the `list` component need, you can also add logic for navigating to whichever page that you want inside this service. This is definitely more scalable but it is a lot more effort to implement.
3. Using state management solution like `redux`. Store the `helpers` in your `store` that any component can keep track of or modify. And then you can use `effect` to add logic like "navigating to a certain page after ...". This is definitely the most complex solution to your problem but it will scale for any similar problem that you have in the future.

Comment: Thank you, @Nam! Option 3 led me to explore and eventually I implemented a BehaviorSubject as observable across the two components - a more basic implementation of redux (btw, I found that NgRx implements redux readily in Angular!).